# How to process refund from control panel?

Tags: expresso-store

The exp:presso store website says that you can process refunds from the control panel, but there is no documentation on what the steps are to do this.

How do you process a refund from the control panel?  We are using the Authorize.Net AIM payment plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Processing refunds from the CP is only supported on some gateways, and Authorize.Net AIM is not one of them unfortunately.

However, we will be adding this soon, so keep an eye out in the next version.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to process refunds is based upon the gateway that you are using. Authorize.net AIM does not allow it however.

To process a refund you need to goto Store > Orders > Details for the order in question then you will see a button for refunds.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but there is no refund button on the order details page.

Comment: I have not used Authorize.net AIM so I am not sure if the gateway supports refunds via the CP.