# Can I add place for notes by the admin in order details?

Tags: expresso-store

I've got a client who would like to add notes to the Order Details of the admin section. For example, a field that the order admin can add the tracking number of the item shipped or if the item was returned/exchanged.

The only place I've seen the admin able to input anything is in the message field of the Order Status - and if I'm not mistaken, that message actually goes to the customer and it not just for the admin's reference.

Is there any way possible to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The order status message is only sent to the customer if you template the status message field in one of your email templates.  Without doing that you shouldn't have a problem with using it an admin only readable field.

Comment: Thanks Justin. This will likely work as a work around, I actually suggested this solution to my client before posting the question but thought i'd ask to see if there was another way.

One other question regarding this post: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13256/how-to-process-refund-from-control-panel

Adrian Macneil mentioned to look for Authorize.net AIM refund support in an upcoming version - any word on that? Thank you.

Comment: The nice thing about the Order Status Message area is that you will be able to see a list of past updates for that order and who posted the update. You could also create additional statuses and emails that would send to people internally with the order status message template tags so people in different departments would be notified about changes.